# prohibiting copy constructor with new standard c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, copy-constructor

hey guys I was trying to create a simple class with copy constructor prohibiting.

```
#include <cstdlib>

// 
class my_stack
{
std::size_t last;
int *data;
std::size_t max_elem;

public :

int top(void) const;
void pop(void);
void push(int);
int size(void) const;
bool empty(void) const;

my_stack();
my_stack(int);
~my_stack();

private:
my_stack(const my_stack&) = delete;
void operator=(const my_stack&) = delete;
};
```

but when i compile it warning appeared

```
 defaulted and deleted functions only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
```

I use g++ compiler. How can I avoid this warning, may be I should use some compiler parameters.

Comment: Did you try the settings that that error message is talking about?

Comment: aha, i tried both of -std=c++0x and -std=gnu++0x, but I've got 2 more same warnings.

Comment: You're doing something wrong. The above code compiles without warnings with `-Wall -std=c++0x` with gcc 4.6, 4.7 and 4.8.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

problem was I used

```
g++ *.cpp -c -std=c++0x
```

instead

```
g++ -std=c++0x *.cpp -c
```